# Getting location data with a server side bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocation, bots

I have a bot that is listening to conversations in a chat app. It is a server side only bot. I was trying to get location data on the users who chat without explicitly asking. I have tried everything I can think of but the best I can do is get the location of the ip address but that is very non-specific: i.e. a coffee shop in Austin gives back a location in Irving, TX.

Comment: please specify, what bot? what server side code?

Comment: it is a bot that uses IBM's Watson to annotate the chat responses - the server side code is in node/express - hosted on IBM Bluemix - the problem is when I get a match to my annotation parameters I want to give the user location specific data